# Multi-site bulk module activation

Tags: 7, multi-sites

For a Drupal multi-site installation, is there any method to activate a module for all sites on the system at once instead of logging into the admin for each site individually?

Comment: You need to enable module at once for drupal multisite installation

Comment: I do not understand what you are trying to say. The drupal multi site is already installed and working. I want to for instance if I am adding the honeypot module to be able to install for all the sites at once instead of logging into the admin for each individual site and activate the module for each site.

Comment: How many backends you have?

Comment: Do you mean how many separate sites? 36 currently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got an answer for this in the Drupal Community on Google+: Use `drush @sites en your_module -y`.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote something to solve this a while back that iterates over every sub directory in the `sites` directory and performs the requested task - [https://github.com/jacobbednarz/drupal-utils](https://github.com/jacobbednarz/drupal-utils/blob/master/multi-site-tasks.sh)